# Tool to configure a Raspberry Pi distro

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, configuration-management

I am having problems with the setup of a headless Raspberry Pi Zero W, and am seeking an app (or script) which would ask me a few questions and write a correctly configured distro to micro SD card for me.  I am speaking particularly of the WiFI configuration., although other stuff would not be unwelcome.

Please note that I have tried  [Pi Bakery](http://www.pibakery.org/), which looks like it does what I want, but won’t write to my SD card  (YMMV)

I would prefer something gratis, but will pay up to about $25. I would prefer a Windows solution, but will accept Linux.

Comment: Sounds familiar :-)

Comment: But very carefully not a duplicate ;-)